# Why I can't get files when I use hgsubversion to import SVN code?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I am a new guy in using Mercurial to maintain my code editions. My company's server is using SVN and I want to maintain my local repository, so I am commit into my Hg when I have a little change to my code. After testing my code carefully, then I can push back my code into SVN server.

I install TortoiseHg and I can clone other open source project to my computer. And I have HgSubversion plugin installed correctly.

Right now I can do the clone operation using following commands:

$ hg clone svn+https://XXXX:8443 test

But after the clone is finished, there is just a folder .hg under test folder.

Why this happen? How can I fix it?

Thanks

Water Lin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might has some files which stored with non-ascii file name in repository. Mercurial can't treats non-ascii file name correctly so far. Have you tried to check out the log? You can do it with command "hg log" to make sure all files had been imported in to Mercurial. Then download and install the extention [fixutf8](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/FixUtf8Extension). That can fix the problem. After you install [fixutf8](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/FixUtf8Extension) you can update current working folder to tip reversion again.

Comment: Yes, the RIGHT ANSWER. Thanks